# Update parent state from child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the state of an object in a child component but nothing seems to work.

ChildComponent.js

```
export default function ChildComponent(props) {

const handleStatus = () => {

        client.post('public/api',someID).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
              props.Details.setData(response.data);
            }
        });
    };

return (
        <div> {props.Details.data} </div>

);}
```

Parent.js

```
const Parent = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    let url = 'public/getData'
    client.get(url).then((response) => {
      setData(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }, []);

 return (
   <div>
      <ChildComponent Details={{data,setData}} />
   </div>
);

}
```

In the child component,after a action, I need to update the data of the parent component but its not getting set. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: open Develepor Tools > Network Tab : from network tab check your request status 200 and provide your browser picture.

Comment: server returning proper results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the setData method to the child component:

```
const Parent = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    let url = 'public/getData'
    client.get(url).then((response) => {
      setData(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }, []);

 return (
   <div>
      <ChildComponent setData={setData} Details={data} />
   </div>
);

}


    export default function ChildComponent(props) {

const handleStatus = () => {

        client.post('public/api',someID).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
              props.setData(response.data);
            }
        });
    };

return (
        <div> {props.Details} </div>

);}
```

Comment: I do need to display some data from parent. In this case, wouldn't the props.details be empty?

Comment: The props.details wouldn't be empty.

Comment: The parent and child components will be re-rendered when the parent state is updated.

Comment: Yes, props.details would be empty since the prop is passed as "Details" not "details".

Comment: Other than that I think it's the correct answer. Did it work for you, op?